# Is there a way in Haskell to check if a minute has passed since the previous current time?

Tags: haskell, time, functional-programming, equality

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to set up a bot that gives you points according if a minute has passed

I've tried looking up ways to get a current time and adding a minute on top of that and check whenever that would equal when a minute has passed such as addUTCTime.

How I would love it to look is just like this

```hs
if(timeNow == timeInAMinute) then sendMsg ("You got a point added!") else return ()
```

I've come to no avail just yet, so I would hope there is some actual way to go about this. I also still have to deal with the IO stuff still. So back to my question, is there a way to check if a minute has passed from the current time?

Comment: A minute has passed **since when**? Now is never in a minute.

Comment: @ziggystar since the last previous current time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would do basically what you're asking:

```
import Data.Time

main :: IO ()
main = do
   t0 <- getCurrentTime
   go t0
 where go tl = do
         t <- getCurrentTime
         if t >= 60`addUTCTime`tl
          then do
             putStrLn "You got a point!"
             go t
          else go tl
```

Of course, this busy waiting in a recursive loop isn't exactly efficient. A much simpler and better solution would be just

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Monad (forever)

main :: IO ()
main = forever $ do
   threadDelay $ 60 * 10^6
   putStrLn "You got a point!"
```